# How to show link of file placed on server using href in php echo tag?

Tags: php, html

Trying to create table using php , i succeed to create table but i want to put link of file on ftp server in td tag , i try with href but it gives error please help me to correct my code.

```
echo "<a href = '../public_html/download/ ".echo $row["FileName"]"'> ".$row["FileName"] "</a>";
```

Comment: _"it gives error"_ could you share it please?

Comment: page isnot working .. only for that line if i comment this line and try then page open successfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed a couple of syntax errors - try this:

```
echo "<a href = '../public_html/download/".$row["FileName"]."'>".$row["FileName"]."</a>";
```

Comment: I also try this one but still page does not open. Is there any other way to show link through php??

Comment: @Yogesh No problem :)